# Responsive Woocommerce Product Grid

Tags: php, html, css, woocommerce, responsive

I like to set products per row for my website depending on device (based on max px width). I like to play with this settings until I have set optimal product display per device.

For example:

- 1 product per row on mobile devices,
- 2 products on tablets
- 4 products on laptops and bigger.

I tried the following:

N1. ot sufficient, cannot set it for different devices

```php
// Change number or products per row to 3
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 3; // 3 products per row
    }
}
```

2. locate style.less file, but with latest version of wordpress file is not present anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use woocommerce anymore, but generally this is something that gets done in css using @media screen

You'll have to look at your woocommerce stylesheets (woocommerce/assets/css/) to see how the columns are already set for different media screens, just do a search for:

```
@media screen
```

And you should see any css styling that's related column displays that may look something like this example:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1218px) {
.col2-set .col-1
},
```

You're basically forcing different screen resolutions to have a different number of columns. You can also do other things for different screen resolutions there as well such as hiding certain items, just look at the css code for it.

Now, I don't know where you got that code from that you originally posted, but if that code is part of woocommerce's core php code then you may need to alter it together with the CSS if that's the case to get the products to appear and be arranged to your liking. However, just mess with the CSS for the time being first for layout purposes.

Hope that helps.